# Youtube video stops automatically as soon as any function is called in my React JS app

Tags: reactjs, function, youtube

I am using YoutubePlayer from 'react-youtube-player' in React JS.
`<YoutubePlayer
   playbackState = 'unstarted'/>`

Now whenever any function is triggered on my webpage it changes its state to unstarted. So if it is playing or paused it gets unstarted.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Use [react-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) npm package. It works fine.